# Search QString character by character

Tags: qt, char, qstring

I'm trying to parse a QString character by character with a while loop, but I can't figure out how to parse an individual character to char type. Here's my code, I know it's not optimal:

```
QString temp = (QString)t[0];
int i = 1;

while (t[i] != " ");
{
    temp.append(t[i]);
    i += 1;
}
```

I've seen the casting with `toLocal8bit` function, but whatever I try I just cannot adapt it to my code.

Qt Creator shows this error:

```
error: conversion from 'const char [2]' to 'QChar' is ambiguous
```

in line with the `while` function call

Comment: Given that `t[x]` seems to refer to some sort of character, the `(QString)t[0]` cast seems very fishy.

Comment: Qt Creator accepted that casting without problem. Initially it gave me an error without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try that :

```
QString test = "test";


for(int i = 0; i< test.length(); i++)
{
    if (test.at(i) != " ")
        test.at(i).toLatin1();
}
```

Comment: Using at function still gives me the same error:

    "error: conversion from 'const char [2]' to 'QChar' is ambiguous"

Comment: This code run like a charm for me, did you adapted it? Feel free to paste your actual code (or a part of it) instead of a snippet

Comment: Yes I adapted it by changing `t[i] != " "` to `t.at(i) != " "`, bit it failed yet again at debugging

Comment: it seems that your cast `QString temp = (QString)t[0];` doesn't work well, do you really need it?

Comment: I modified my code to only declare `temp` but not initialise it, and I've also commented out `temp.append(t[i])`, but the error persists

Comment: It worked after I casted `" "` to `(QString)" "`! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

You can use C++ 11 range based for loop

```
for (auto chr : text)
{
    if (!chr.isDigit()) // for exmpl.
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation how this code solves the issue